# Is there a method to find the most specific pattern for a string?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm wondering whether there is a way to generate the most specific regular expression (if such a thing exists) that matches a given string. Here's an illustration of what I want the method to do:

```
str = "(17 + 31)"
find_pattern(str)
# => /^\(\d+ \+ \d+\)$/ (or something more specific)
```

My intuition was to use `Regex.new` to accumulate the desired pattern by looping through `str` and checking for known patterns like `\d`, `\s`, and so on. I suspect there is an easy way for doing this.

Comment: The most specific pattern is the string itself, you would need at least couple of strings to generate common pattern and it would not be ease I'm afraid.

Comment: @BroiSatse Thank you; I did have that fear too. I'll play with the idea of finding the common pattern among at least two (different) strings instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in essence an algorithm compression problem. The simplest way to match a list of known strings is to use `Regexp.union` factory method, but that just tries each string in turn, it does not do anything "clever":

```
combined_rx = Regexp.union( "(17 + 31)", "(17 + 45)" )
 => /\(17\ \+\ 31\)|\(17\ \+\ 45\)/
```

This can still be useful to construct multi-stage validators, without you needing to write loops to check them all.

However, a generic pattern matcher that could figure out what you *mean* to match from examples is not really possible. There are too many ways in which you could consider strings to be similar or not. The closest I could think of would be genetic programming where you supply a large list of should match/should not match strings and the code guesses at the best regex by constructing random `Regexp` objects (a challenge in itself) and seeing how accurately they match and don't match your examples. The best matchers could be combined and mutated and tried again until you got 100% accuracy. This might be a fun project, but ultimately much more effort for most purposes than writing the regular expressions yourself from a description of the problem.

If your problem is heavily constrained - e.g. any example integer could always be replaced by `\d+`, any example space by `\s+` etc, then you could work through the string replacing "matchable units", in fact using the *same* regular expressions checked in turn. E.g. if you match `\A\d+` then *consume* the match from the string, and add `\d+` to your regex. Then take the remainder of the string and look for next matching pattern. Working this way will have its limitations (you must know the full set of patterns you want to match in advance, and all examples would have to be unambiguous). However, it is more tractable than a genetic program.